# MaxLabels for Amazon Rekognition Video not working

Tags: amazon-rekognition

The `MaxLabels` argument works on the Amazon Rekognition Image but not using a Video. I have this PHP payload I use:

```
            'ClientRequestToken' => (string)Str::uuid(),
            'JobTag' => VideoOperations::REKOGNITION_LABEL_DETECTION,
            'NotificationChannel' => [
                'RoleArn' => config('rekognition.notification_channel.role_arn'),
                'SNSTopicArn' => config('rekognition.notification_channel.sns_arn'),
            ],
            'MinConfidence' => config('rekognition.min_confidence'),
            'MaxLabels' => config('rekognition.max_labels'),
            'Video' => [
                'S3Object' => [
                    'Bucket' => config('rekognition.bucket'),
                    'Name' => $video->filename
                ],
            ]
```

I checked the official github AWSDocs Rekognition samples and could not find an implementation of the MaxLabels on a Video Rekognition.

Is it not supported? https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-rekognition-developer-guide/search?q=MaxLabels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi this was answered by AWS on this [link.](https://repost.aws/questions/QU6Nedi_ltSGCJNc0mtQaZoA#ANa_Waw8HxQAGGnS9K-q6IDw)

> Dear customer,

Currently, "MaxLabels" is not supported in labels detection for video, i.e., in StartLabelDetection and GetLabelDetection API's.

In GetLabelDetection API, "MaxResults" can be used to specify the maximum number of results to return per paginated API call. However, "MaxResults" in video is different from "MaxLabels" in image. Please see details of video GetLabelDetection "MaxResults" in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/APIReference/API_GetLabelDetection.html#API_GetLabelDetection_RequestSyntax. Please see details of image DetectLabels "MaxLabels" in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/APIReference/API_DetectLabels.html#API_DetectLabels_RequestSyntax.

Thank you for using Rekognition Video.